# Event Handling with Scenebuilder and Eclipse: Error Event Handler not in Namespace or Error in Script

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I've looked at the other questions that have the same problems, and I have all of the solutions to those implemented but I still get this error:

```
Error resolving onMouseClicked='#handleButtonAction', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
```

Here is my main, controller, and fxml documents in order:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,562.0,389.0);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class SampleController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private ImageView msgIcon, connectionIcon, settingsIcon, powerIcon, msgUp, connectionUp, settingsUp;
    private Pane connectionPane, msgPane, settingsPane, tabPane;


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getTarget() == msgIcon)
        {
            msgPane.setVisible(true);
            connectionPane.setVisible(false);
            settingsPane.setVisible(false);     

            msgUp.setVisible(true);
            connectionUp.setVisible(false);
            settingsUp.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(event.getTarget() == connectionIcon)
        {
            msgPane.setVisible(false);
            connectionPane.setVisible(true);
            settingsPane.setVisible(false);

            msgUp.setVisible(false);
            connectionUp.setVisible(true);
            settingsUp.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(event.getTarget() == settingsIcon)
        {
            msgPane.setVisible(false);
            connectionPane.setVisible(false);
            settingsPane.setVisible(true);

            msgUp.setVisible(false);
            connectionUp.setVisible(false);
            settingsUp.setVisible(true);

        }
        else if(event.getTarget() == powerIcon)
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
}
```

FXML:
There's a lot here but the event handler was just added for the ImageView msgIcon. This solely caused the error. If I removed the OnMouseClicked = ... there is no error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?package application?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="529.0" prefWidth="459.0" style="-fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="msgPane" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="469.0" prefWidth="459.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c2049;">
         <children>
            <Pane layoutX="141.0" prefHeight="467.0" prefWidth="318.0">
               <children>
                  <JFXTextField focusColor="#405aa801" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="428.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="248.0" promptText="Messege..." style="-fx-border-radius: 10 10 10 10; -fx-background-color: #574387; -fx-background-radius: 10 10 10 10; -fx-prompt-text-fill: #ffffff;" unFocusColor="#4d4d4d00">
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </JFXTextField>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="35.0" layoutX="275.0" layoutY="430.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Sent_50px_2.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <JFXTextArea editable="false" prefHeight="414.0" prefWidth="318.0" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane prefHeight="467.0" prefWidth="141.0" style="-fx-border-color: #949299; -fx-border-style: hidden solid hidden hidden;">
               <children>
                  <JFXListView prefHeight="467.0" prefWidth="140.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c2049;" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Pane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="459.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c2049; -fx-border-color: #949299; -fx-border-style: hidden hidden solid hidden;">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="settingsIcon" fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="31.0" layoutX="286.0" layoutY="17.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Settings_64px_1.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="connectionIcon" fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="31.0" layoutX="156.0" layoutY="17.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Add_New_48px_1.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="msgIcon" fitHeight="41.0" fitWidth="38.0" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="14.0" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Video_Chat_64px_1.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="powerIcon" fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="24.0" layoutX="404.0" layoutY="21.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Shutdown_52px.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="msgUp" fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="17.0" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="44.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Sort_Up_52px.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="connectionUp" fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="17.0" layoutX="163.0" layoutY="44.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Sort_Up_52px.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="settingsUp" fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="17.0" layoutX="293.0" layoutY="44.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Resources/icons8_Sort_Up_52px.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Pane fx:id="msgPane" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="469.0" prefWidth="459.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c2049;" visible="false">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="108.0" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Theme:" textFill="#dcdada">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <JFXComboBox layoutX="256.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="106.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4f3b7c;" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Pane fx:id="connectionPane" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="469.0" prefWidth="459.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c2049;" visible="false">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="90.0" layoutY="59.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="Username" textFill="#a9a9a9">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <JFXTextField focusColor="#4f3b7c" layoutX="193.0" layoutY="59.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" style="-fx-prompt-text-fill: #a9a9a9; -fx-text-inner-color: #a9a9a9;" />
            <Label layoutX="77.0" layoutY="103.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Port Number" textFill="#a9a9a9">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <JFXTextField focusColor="#4f3b7c" layoutX="193.0" layoutY="103.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" style="-fx-prompt-text-fill: #a9a9a9; -fx-text-inner-color: #a9a9a9;" />
            <Label layoutX="97.0" layoutY="151.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="Target IP" textFill="#a9a9a9">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <JFXTextField focusColor="#4f3b7c" layoutX="193.0" layoutY="151.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" style="-fx-prompt-text-fill: #a9a9a9; -fx-text-inner-color: #a9a9a9;" />
            <JFXToggleButton layoutX="82.0" layoutY="199.0" text="Show Time" textFill="DARKGRAY" toggleColor="#4f3b7c" toggleLineColor="#7a5fb7" />
            <JFXToggleButton layoutX="255.0" layoutY="199.0" text="Hosting" textFill="DARKGRAY" toggleColor="#4f3b7c" toggleLineColor="#7a5fb7" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="93.0" layoutY="280.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="106.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4f3b7c;" text="Save Connection" textFill="WHITE" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="258.0" layoutY="280.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="106.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4f3b7c;" text="Load Connection" textFill="WHITE" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="93.0" layoutY="347.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="106.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4f3b7c;" text="Validate" textFill="WHITE" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="258.0" layoutY="347.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="106.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4f3b7c;" text="Connect" textFill="WHITE" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I feel it is something fundamental I am missing/not understanding. Please let me know what you think my issue is. Thanks.

Comment: `onMouseClicked` is not a handler for `ActionEvent` but for `MouseEvent`. Since `MouseEvent` cannot be assigned to `ActionEvent` `handleButtonAction` cannot be used for `onMouseClicked` events.